Title of movie from the 90s with dead girl under the surface of frozen lake
I'm looking for the title of a movie I saw around 20 years ago.
I can only recollect few facts (I don't remember any actor and don't know if any of them was famous), but hopefully these facts are sufficient to determine the title:

I saw the movie no later than 1997, and it was a recent movie back then (so, I believe it was from the mid 90s).
Towards the end of the movie (maybe in the final scene) the girl dies underwater in a frozen lake (or sea). The scene is filmed from above, so we see the girl beneath the layer of ice, staring towards the surface.
I am pretty confident that it was a north-american movie, in English, but I can't be 100% sure, since I saw it in a dubbed version (while I was on a ferryboat!).
As far as I recall, I presume it was a mainstream Hollywood movie.
Color.
Live action.


You might want to provide a more descriptive question title

Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I modified the title as requested. I don't remember any other details, unfortunately, but I'm confident I could recognize the movie if I saw it

Maybe To Die For (1995), with Nicole Kidman and Joaquin Phoenix? 
At the end Kidman's character is killed off-camera and the shot later pans over her face under the ice. 
Not sure if I can link to it because of copyright, but the full movie is on YouTube and it's around the 1:22 mark. 
EDIT:
Here is a link to the complete movie, cued up to the shots of Nicole Kidman under the ice. Below is a still frame of that visual:


Is that picture from the movie? I thought Nicole Kidman was the one who got frozen in the lake, and that doesn't look like her (and I don't remember that shot in the film, either).

It's supposed to be. I doubted it myself, but it's from a blog about the film so I just went with it. I'll remove it for now and update the answer if I find another one.

Albeit a very good guess, this is not the movie I saw. To Die For sticks to a mockumentary format that certainly was not in the movie I'm looking for. I hope somebody will come up with other suggestions
